# Is there a clustering algorithm that works with only pairwise distances as input?

Tags: clustering

My data are places for which I know all pairwise travel times (='distances'), and I want to cluster those places minimising the total pairwise travel time inside a cluster.

- K-means can't be used because it's centroid-based and the 'distance' is a duration that is provided, not computed thanks to coordinates
- DBSCAN can't be used because it excludes outliners and I want to include each places in a cluster (not 100% sure for this one)

Bonus: a Java library would be much appreciated

Comment: have you tried hierarchical clustering? I'm not a java programmer but in python, you can input the distance matrix consisting of pair-wise distances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a classic Graph-Based Clustering problem in which each location is a node and you have the distances between them. Forgetting about concept of graphs and graph-based algorithm which might be complicating, I directly jump to your answer.

The most well-known algorithm is [Spectral Clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering). There are tones of tutorial out there and it is well implemented in all programming languages [including Java](http://haifengl.github.io/api/java/smile/clustering/SpectralClustering.html).

I briefly explain but do not Panic if you are not familiar with Math terms. They are pretty intuitive and easy. You just need to follow a good tutorial.

1. Calculate the Similarity Matrix (often referred to as Affinity Matrix in literature). As you have *distance* matrix you have several ways to do it. Simplest starts from saying $sim = \frac{1}{dist}$ till more sophisticated ones which use [Gaussian Kernels for calculating similarity](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17352/why-do-we-use-a-gaussian-kernel-as-a-similarity-metric).
2. Calculate the [Laplacian Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering#Definitions) out of similarity matrix.
3. Calculate eigenvectors and eigenvalues in order to embedd your data points into their eigen-space (like exactly what we do in PCA)
4. Use a simple clustering algorithm like K-Means to cluster points in that space